# How to do conditional formatting to date in less than two weeks?

Tags: excel, vba, date, conditional-formatting

This is what I've tried so  far

'Set conditional formatting for tasks that have deadline in two weeks
Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
"=AND($M4>=TODAY(),($M4<DATEADD(""d"",14,TODAY()))"

I can't seem to make the condition do anything. This is for a table column. StopIfTrue = false.
I have a similar conditional formatting before this

Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
"=$M4<TODAY()"

And it works fine. What am I missing?

Comment: `$M$<TODAY()+14`? Not sure exactly what you're trying to do

Comment: Trying to do conditional formatting to dates less than two weeks from today. I edited the post.